# How to pass own variables on form without using input

Tags: php, html, forms, action

want to submit a form with name and quantity but i want to pass a get variable to the form without input. When the form is submitted the get variable for quantity is pass but i want also to pass the name quantity which is displayed already. Can i do this either through action="site.php?name=theName" or how can i do this.

"<"form  action='site.php?name={$name_row['name']}' method='GET'>

Comment: please provide some code ! which highlight your question and help to answer

Comment: Just add a hidden input? `<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $name_row['name']?>" />`

Answer (score 1):

Using GET method in forms is not recommended, maybe you want to use hidden inputs?

```
<form action='site.php' method='POST'>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?=$name_row['name']?>">
</form>
```

You can use it with GET too

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the variable passed to be displayed, you can use a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'] ?>"/>
```

If you **don't want to use any input**, of course you can pass them in form `action`:

```
<form action="somewhere.php?name="<?php echo $_GET['name'] ?>" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have 3 most popular methods**

i. Input type hidden

```
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?=$variabel?>'>
```

ii. Add on form GET method

```
<form action='site.php?xyz=<?=$variabel?>'>

</form>
```

iii. User $_SESSION

```
<?php $_SESSION['xyz'] = variabel; ?>
```